# Using a prepared statement for dynamic queries

Tags: java

i have wr-written the code now i get a nullpointer exception, please can you help me or just point me in the right direction

i am still a bigginer java programmer and this is my last assignment whic is due tommorow

```
 import java.sql.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;

 public class QueryDB_N
 {
private Connection con = null;
String userID,firstName,lastName,name,symbol;

public QueryDB_N() throws Exception
{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:StockTracker";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (url);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    PreparedStatement pStmt = null;

    BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter User ID: ");
    userID = dataIn.readLine();

    System.out.println("\nStock holdings for User: " + userID);
    System.out.println("Stock  - Description");
    System.out.println("------- ----------------------------");

    pStmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT  FROM (Users INNER JOIN UserStocks ON Users.userID = UserStocks.userID) INNER JOIN Stocks ON UserStocks.symbol = Stocks.symbol");

        pStmt.setString(1, userID);
        pStmt.setString(2, symbol);

        System.out.println("\n" + userID + "\t" + firstName + "\t" + lastName + "\t");
        System.out.println("\t\t" + symbol + "\t" + name);

     System.out.println("\n\nReport done.");
}


public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
{
    QueryDB_N q = new QueryDB_N();
}
}
```

---

i have re-written the code again now it is returning the values as null instead of the actual symbol and description,i really need your help please i have tried everything i just cant get it to work properly

```
/*
Chapter 11: the QueryDB_N Class
Programmer: Jacques Duvenage
Date: November, 2014
Program Name: QueryDB_N.java
 */

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class QueryDB_N
{
private Connection con = null;
String userID,firstName,lastName,name,symbol;

public QueryDB_N() throws Exception
{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:StockTracker";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (url);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    PreparedStatement pStmt = null;

    BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter User ID: ");
    userID = dataIn.readLine();

    System.out.println("\nStock holdings for User: " + userID);
    System.out.println("Stock  - Description");
    System.out.println("------- ----------------------------");

    pStmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM (Users INNER JOIN UserStocks ON Users.? = UserStocks.?) INNER JOIN Stocks ON UserStocks.symbol = Stocks.symbol");

        pStmt.setString(1, userID);
        pStmt.setString(2, symbol);


        System.out.println(symbol + "\t" + name);

     System.out.println("\n\nReport done.");
}


public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
{
    QueryDB_N q = new QueryDB_N();
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you inserting data to the database when the function is called getUserID? You should be using SELECT query instead of INSERT.

Comment: you prepare 2 statements but actually execute only one. pStmt var on UserStocks is erased by Stocks statement before it is actually executed.

Comment: i am not sure how to implement the select query, please help

Comment: and the reason i am using 2 statements is because the stock description is in the stocks table whereas the userID ans stock type is in the userStocks table, please help

Comment: Best thing to do now is to learn SQL and JDBC: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html

Answer (score 0):

In this way only You run 2 query in same PS statement. This is error.

```html
public static void getUserID(Connection con, PreparedStatement pStmt, String userID, String stockSymbol) throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        pStmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO UserStocks VALUES(?,?)");
        pStmt.setString(1, userID);
        pStmt.setString(2, stockSymbol);
        pStmt.executeQuery();
        pstmt.close();        
        pStmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Stocks VALUES(?,?)");
        pStmt.setString(1, userID);
        pStmt.setString(2, stockSymbol);
        pStmt.executeQuery();
        pStmt.close();               
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
```